# Do we know of more than one occurance where Prime Gap=1?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

A [prime gap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap) $g_n$ is the difference between two prime numbers, and as we know, the first two primes are 2 and 3, thus their prime gap is 1;

$$
g_n = p_{n+1}-p_n=\big\{ n=1 \big\}=3 -2=1.
$$

But have we *found* any other occurrences, except for the gap between primes 2 and 3, where the prime gap is 1?

(For example the  twin prime conjecture shows that $g_n = 2$ for infinitely many integers $n$, but is there anything about $g_n=1$?)

Comment: All primes except $2$ are odd, so their difference is even.

Comment: Pretty sure it is impossible since all multiples of 2 are all obviously even and not prime

Comment: Everyone, please keep in mind that if the answer to this question seems kind of obvious, that doesn't mean that it's a *bad question*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is impossible for any two prime numbers $p,q\geq 3$ to have difference one. This would mean that a number $p$ is prime and $p+1$ is also prime. But one of them then would have to be even so cannot be a prime number, if you assume them to be at least three.

Answer (score 2):

If the gap between two numbers is $1$, one of them is even. So if they are both prime numbers, one of them has to be $2$ (the only even prime number). It should answer your question...